# How to flatten a List of Futures in Scala

Tags: list, scala, flatten

I want to take this val:

```
val f = List(Future(1), Future(2), Future(3))
```

Perform some operation on it (I was thinking flatten)

```
f.flatten
```

And get this result

```
scala> f.flatten = List(1,2,3)
```

If the flatten method isn't appropriate here, that's fine.  As long as I get to the result.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen if one of the `Future`s fails?

Comment: If any of the futures fail, then I want the whole thing to fail.  This is part of a homework question, so I wasn't looking to get the whole thing solved for me.  But basically, I still have to figure out how to determine if any of the futures failed and if they did, I just kill the whole thing.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`Future.sequence` takes a `List[Future[T]]` and returns a `Future[List[T]]`.

You can do

```
Future.sequence(f)
```

and then use `map` or `onComplete` on it to access the list of values.

Comment: This is the output I'm getting:  

scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3227f076

Is this expected?  It is transforming a List[Future[T]] into a Future[List[T]].

But I was expecting something along the lines of:

scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = Future(List(1,2,3))

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's a `Future`. Now you can handle it (either map, use onComplete or anything you want). The result inside the `Future` will be your list in case of success

Comment: `Future` doesn't normally print what's inside it (that would mean blocking). If you do `Future(1)`, you'll get something that looks like `scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@78393fdb`. For testing you can use something like `Await.result(f, 2.seconds)`.

Comment: @mikejones1477 it's almost always preferable not to block. Consider handling the result asynchronously

Comment: Yes.  I wasn't planning on blocking for my final result.  But in the interest of learning, I'd like to ask what you mean about asynchronously?

Comment: I mean in a non-blocking way. Mapping over a future is already asynchronous, since the code will run eventually in the future (if the computation has success)