# Change a Seq[Future[Boolean]] to a Future[Seq[Boolean]]

Tags: scala, dictionary, future

I am having a working solution, but I just wanted to ask if there is a better way of doing it. Basically, I am faced with a sequence of Future each holding one object with a Boolean as the only attribute. And I want to run a `forall` on the sequence. I was just wondering if there is a more elegant solution that does not require an Await. For comparison, this is my solution now:

```
Seq[Future[Object[Boolean]]] map 
{ Await.result(Future[Object[Boolean]], Duration.inf) } 
forall Boolean
```

So, is there any way I can map a `Seq[Future[Object]]` to a `Future[Seq[Object]]` without using `Await`?

SOLVED in comment, waiting for comment to be transformed into an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717249/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-futures-in-scala - while not an exact duplicate, it answers the last question in the post, and I believe you can go on from there.

Comment: Oh perfect. I should have put more time into research. Will you transform your comment to an answer so I can choose it as best answer?