# How to get Future[Seq[Person]] instead of Seq[Future[Person]]

Tags: scala, future

I have two external call which

1. Which gives Future[Seq[People]]
2. Which takes person_id and returns person_status as Future[String]

I need to update each person status using second call from the sequence available in first call. This is how I tried,

```
getFuturePeople.map( (seqPeople : Seq[People]) => {
     seqPeople.map(person => getStatus(person._id).status).map(status => {
     //Update status for this person but I get Seq[Future[Peoson]]
   }) 
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flatten a List of Futures in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717249/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-futures-in-scala)

Comment: @Jasper-M That question asks how to get a `List[A]`, not a  `Future[List[A]]`. That the answer happens to be similar is immaterial.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I don't fully agree that the questions don't qualify as duplicates, but ok sure, take one of the other countless questions that ask for `sequence`...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use can use `Future.sequence` to transform the result, eg:

`val futureOfSeq = Future.sequence(seqOfFuture)`

Answer (score 5):

you need to traverse on `List` as `Future.traverse`.

Example,

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def getFuturePeople = Future { List("Steven", "Wilson", "Michael") }
def getStatus(name: String) = Future { s"$name updated" }
```

Now, like what you tried, you get `Future[List[Future[String]]]`.

```
getFuturePeople.map { people => people.map { p => getStatus(p) } }
```

**1) So, instead of just mapping on `list of people`, do `Future.traverse`**,

```
val updatedPeople: Future[List[String]] = getFuturePeople.flatMap { people =>
       Future.traverse(people) { p =>
         getStatus(p)
       }
 }
```

**2) What also works is once you map on `list of people` and get `List[Future[A]]`, use `Future.sequence` to convert to `Future[List[A]]`,**

```
val updatedPeopleUsingSeq: Future[List[String]] = getFuturePeople.flatMap { people =>
       Future.sequence {
         people.map(getStatus)
       }
}
```

Comment: This has the right information, but it is so verbose that it is hard to see it and I nearly didn't bother reading it all. REPL output is hard to read and you don't really need to show your working like this, you can just show the solution with a couple of lines of explanation.

Comment: It is also better if you use the same types and names as the original question where possible. (e.g. `Seq` rather than `List`, `getFuturePeople` rather than `getPeople`)

Answer (score 0):

use Future.sequence like this:

```
val returnedFuture :Seq[Future[People]] = Seq(Future.successful(People))

val flattenedFuture:Future[Seq[Peope]] = Future.sequence(returnedFuture)
```