# How to wait for list of futures with for comprehension in Scala?

Tags: scala, future

I have list of models ids and I want to evaluate all the models and print their status. I get from my service Future of models, and I want to wait for the evaluation of future and then run the rest of my code.

I am stuck here:

```
   private def checkInvalidModels(modelsIds: Seq[Int]): Unit = {
        val fModels = modelsList.map(id => modelsService.get(id))
        val res = for{
              model <- fModels
            } yield (model)

        res.map( model => println(model.status))

    }
```

the last map is not working, he cant recognize my model. what did I miss?

Comment: Does this answer it? [How to get Future Seq Person  instead of Seq Future Person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606274/how-to-get-futureseqperson-instead-of-seqfutureperson)

Comment: Use `Future.traverse` and return a `Future[Unit]`